# Not working: indexing the words in a file in a dict by first letter

Tags: python, dictionary

I have to write a function based on a open file that has one lowercase word per line. I have to return a dictionary with keys in single lowercase letters and each value is a list of the words from the file that starts with that letter. (The keys in the dictionary are from only the letters of the words that appear in the file.)

This is my code:

```
def words(file):    
    line = file.readline()
    dict = {}
    list = []        
    while (line != ""):
        list = line[:].split()
        if line[0] not in dict.keys():
            dict[line[0]] = list
        line = file.readline()            
    return dict
```

However, when I was testing it myself, my function doesn't seem to return all the values. If there are more than two words that start with a certain letter, only the first one shows up as the values in the output. What am I doing wrong?

For example, the file should return:

```
{'a': ['apple'], 'p': ['peach', 'pear', 'pineapple'],  \
 'b': ['banana', 'blueberry'], 'o': ['orange']}, ...
```

... but returns ...

```
{'a': ['apple'], 'p': ['pear'],  \
 'b': ['banana'], 'o': ['orange']}, ...
```

Comment: A few tips on Pythonic programming style: to iterate over every line of a file, instead of `while line: <a bunch of stuff> line = file.readline` simply use `for line in file: <a bunch of stuff>`.

Comment: Do you want code or just help?

Comment: Naming variables `list` and `dict` is a bad idea; you've lost access to the built-in list and dictionary classes.

Comment: Is this a homework problem? When you told Oscar "we're not supposed to use "defaultdict" or "collections"" you seem to be implying that. Please don't ask homework problems on SO.

Comment: Also on Python style, never, *ever* call a variable `dict` or `list`; these are builtins: you've made it so that code like `list()` won't work any more. Give them names which have meaning, not which indicate type.

Comment: @SpliFF homework questions are fine on SO within certain limits; questioners are expected to show what they've done so far, and not expect outright answers. (That said, I provided something that should work as an outright answer because I feel that students should see what real practical code looks like and not have to trudge through these sorts of exercises with arbitrary restrictions.)

Comment: You need to add a line that deals with the case where the dict key is already in your dict. That is your main problem. Also, bad idea naming your variables list and dict

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution, it takes into account the case where there are words starting with the same character in more than one line, and it doesn't use `defaultdict`. I also simplified the function a bit:

```
def words(file):
    dict = {}
    for line in file:
        lst = line.split()
        dict.setdefault(line[0], []).extend(lst)
    return dict
```

Comment: @YounsuW I updated my answer, tell me if it's working for you

Comment: You can simplify this further using dictionary methods: `dict.setdefault(line[0], []).extend(lst)`.

Comment: you can create your own default dict  ;)

Comment: @JoelCornett That was my first idea, but OP is not allowed to use `defaultdict`: see the first comment

Comment: Hehe yeah,  I figured.  But maybe it's possible to create a class that subclasses dict, and overrides the default get/set with some code that handles a keyerror. No?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't adding to the list for each additional letter. Try:

```
if line[0] not in dict.keys():
    dict[line[0]] = list
else:
    dict[line[0]] += list
```

Comment: if line[0] not in dict.keys():
    dict[line[0]] = list

what does this mean? that if the letter if not in the dictionary keys, that it should be assigned to list?

Comment: I would be doing `line[0] not in dict`, not `line[0] not in dict.keys()`; it's more efficient and shorter.

Comment: It would probably be clearer to use `dict.extend` instead of `+=`.

Comment: @YounsuW: I just copied the syntax you were already using. The difference is I've added an `else` condition that adds more items to the existing list that was assigned to the letter (`+=` adds something to the existing value of the variable on the left side. It is a shorter version of `dict[line[0]] = dict[line[0]] + list`. When you add two lists you get a new list with the items from both lists, ie: a join.

Comment: @SpliFF notice that I didn't suggest `+=` won't *work*, I said using the `.extend` method would be *clearer* (it possibly doesn't help my own clarity that I typoed `dict[line[0]].extend` as `dict.extend`, which doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem is that `dict[line[0]] = list` replaces the value for the new key.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like every dictionary entry should be a list. Use the [append](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method on the dictionary key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
def words(file):
    dict = {}
    line = file.readline()
    while (line != ""):
        my_key = line[0].lower()
        dict.setdefault(my_key, []).extend(line.split() )
        line = file.readline()
    return dict
```

Comment: line.split() will give you a list, are you sure you want to append that?

Answer (score 0):

Sacrificing performance (to a certain extent) for elegance:

```
with open(whatever) as f: words = f.read().split()

result = {
    first: [word for word in words if word.startswith(first)]
    for first in set(word[0] for word in words)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
def words(file):
    dct = {}
    for line in file:
        word = line.strip()
        try:
            dct[word[0]].append(word)
        except KeyError:
            dct[word[0]] = [word]
    return dct
```

The first time a new letter is found, there will be a KeyError, subsequent occurances of the letter will cause the word to be appended to the existing list

Another approach would be to prepopulate the dict with the keys you need

```
import string
def words(file):
    dct = dict.fromkeys(string.lowercase, [])
    for line in file:
        word = line.strip()
        dct[word[0]] = dct[word[0]] + [word]
    return dct
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to work out why `dct[word[0]] += [word]` won't work